# CSS not() clause does not fire

Tags: css, css-selectors

Sure this is a too easy question but incredibly I did not understande why this code does not run as desired.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="remember">
    <a class="foo">INSIDE text (Should be black)</a>
  </div> 
</div>

<br>
<a class="foo">OUTSIDE text (Should be red)</a>
```

CSS:

```
div:not(.remember) .foo
{
  color:red;
}
```

Here the [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zgzvrnwj/).

I would like that every item with class `.foo` OUTSIDE a parent with class `.remember` will be red, but it seems that "not" clause does not fire.

Where is my error?

Comment: Give `:not(.remember) > .foo` a try. `:not(.remember)` also selects the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` elements as well, hence the nested `.foo` was treated by `:not(.remember) .foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your upper most `<div>` doesn't have `.remember`, it passes your selection and so `.foo` has styles changed. Use the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators).

Your selection requires that the parent that isn't `.remember` is also a `<div>`, because you haven't given your second `.foo` a parent, in this case, its parent will be `<body>`. If you don't make this restriction, it is black in colour, as expected.

```css
:not(.remember) > .foo {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="remember">
    <a class="foo">INSIDE text (Should be black)</a>
  </div> 
</div>

<br>
<a class="foo">OUTSIDE text (Should be red)</a>
```

Comment: The first should be black. It isn't because of the parents parent div which doesn't have the class `remember`

Comment: Thanks George, your solution is perfect for my problem. I did not think about fact that "upper most <div> doesn't have .remember, it passes selection". It is very specific and not so general like Ivaylo's one but perfect and very compact for my specific need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp8v118z/3/)

- The `a.foo` was not inside a div, it is fixed. The `div:not(.remember) .foo` expects the link to be inside of a `div`.

  ```
  <div>
    <div class="remember">
      <a class="foo">INSIDE text (Should be inherited)</a>
    </div> 

    <br>
    <a class="foo">OUTSIDE text (Should be red)</a>    
  </div>
  ```
- There was no style for `div.reminder .foo`, it should specifically inherit from the parent style.

  ```
  div:not(.remember) .foo
  {     
      color:red;
  }
  div.remember .foo { color: inherit; }
  ```

In the above fiddle, I added the first line which should represent any styles already set to the page (parent containers and etc). Its purpose is to play with it in order to see how the inner content behaves. You can remove it safely, the behavior will be as expected. 
The `div.remember .foo` will simply inherit them rather than force something else. However

Comment: I don't want to FORCE black color to item inside `.remember` div to override more general declaration. I would like to "apply red color to all elements EXCEPT those child of a container with `.remember`

Comment: I'm sorry but it not the solution. Again you are specifing colors twice. In addition my example use "color" declaration but problem is more general and should be solved with any declaration like "display:none" for example.

Comment: @LucaDetomi, see my update. The fist css line is optional, I added it so I can play with the fiddle, and you too if you wanted. The `color: inherit` is the thing that makes it work, so you cannot skip it in my solution. You can use `inherit` with whatever other styles you have in the same manner

Comment: @Luca, as I said, the first line in the fiddle is to play with it, I updated it - http://jsfiddle.net/Lp8v118z/3/, now it is green, remove it and it will be black. Also, the code in the post is what you actually need :)

Comment: Thanks Ivaylo, I voted up your solution even if at the end I accepted George's one. Yours is more general and it runs correctly not regarding hierarchy of child elements of `.remember` tag, but others is more compact and perfect for specific situation explained in question. Thanks anyway for your help :-)

Comment: @LucaDetomi, glad I helped. My solution was intentionally based on your initial example.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.foo{color:red;}
.remember a.foo{color:black;}
```

This will cause all .foo elements to be red, unless it is nested inside the parent .remember, it will then be black.

http://jsfiddle.net/92gnt7qt/

Comment: Please read other comments on other answers: I don't want to FORCE black color to item inside `.remember` div to override more general declaration. I would like to "apply red color to all elements EXCEPT those child of a container with `.remember`"

Comment: You should update your question instead of having people read other answers. Will have another look for you.

Comment: Check out this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector